# All fractions which can be written simultaneously in the forms $\frac{7k-5}{5k-3}$ and $\frac{6l-1}{4l-3}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, fractions

Find all fractions which can be written simultaneously in the forms $\frac{7k-5}{5k-3}$ and $\frac{6l-1}{4l-3}$

for some integers $k,l$.

> Please check my answer and tell me is correct or not....
>
> $$\frac{43}{31},\frac{31}{27},1,\frac{55}{39},\frac{5}{3},\frac{61}{43},\frac{19}{13},\frac{13}{9}$$

Comment: What is your proof? How did you come to these answers, and what makes you sure there are no others?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose there is integer $p$ which can be written as $\frac{6l-1}{4l-3}$ and $\frac{7k-5}{5k-3}$.

$$p= \frac{6l-1}{4l-3} =\frac{7k-5}{5k-3}$$

$$\implies kl+8k+l=6$$

$$\implies(k+1)l=(6-8k)\implies l=\frac{-2(4k-3)}{(k+1)}$$.

Which gives following integer solutions:

$(k,l)=(-15,-9),(-8,-10),(-3,-15),(-2,-22),(0,6),(1,-1),(6,-6),(13,7)$. These all sets of values will give you a new such number. I shall let you conclude now.

Comment: You are omitting the pairs that correspond to $k=1,6,13.$

Comment: What about $(k,l)=(1,-1)$, $(6,-6)$ and $(13,7)$?

Comment: Sorry for missing those . I am gonna edit it.

Answer (score 4):

$$\frac{7k-5}{5k-3}=\frac{6l-1}{4l-3}$$

$$28kl-20l-21k+15=30kl-18l-5k+3$$

$$2kl+2l+16k-12=0$$

$$kl+l+8k-6=0$$

either:

$$l(1+k)=2(3-4k)$$
so
$$l=2\frac{3-4k}{1+k}$$

or:

$$k(l+8)=6-l$$

so

$$k=\frac{6-l}{l+8}$$

Let's go with this second one to complement the other answer.

Then $$k=-\frac{l-6}{l+8}=-\left(\frac{l+8-14}{l+8}\right)=-\left(1-\frac{14}{l+8}\right)$$

We want $l+8=\pm(1,2,7,14)$

So $l=-7,-9,-6,-10,-1,-15,6,-22$ or more nicely ordered $$l=-22,-15,-10,-9,-7,-6,-1,6$$

The pairs are then $(l,k)=$ $(-22,-2)$, $(-15,-3)$, $(-10,-8)$, $(-9,-15)$,  $(-7,13)$, $(-6,6)$, $(-1,1)$, $(-22,-2)$, $(6,0)$, 
or that the fractions are

$$\frac{19}{13},\frac{13}{9},\frac{61}{43},\frac{55}{39},\frac{43}{31},\frac{37}{27},1,\frac{5}{3}.$$

Comment: Seems, then, that the asker was off on just one fraction:  With respect to $k=6$ OP has $\frac{31}{27}$, rather than the correct value of $\frac{37}{27}$.  I'd say the OP did pretty good!  Very nice answer, snulty, deserves to stand out with more votes, but I surely voted up your answer.

Comment: I hope you know that, speed in answering is always a measure of quality.  In speedy posts, those who answer immediately, only to edit their answer 10 or more times to correct mistakes, many needing to explain further, or continue editing, that others who took care to take the time needed for a complete  high-quality posts, save us from.  I simply think you put the most time and consideration in creating a high quality post...

Answer (score 3):

We have that $$\frac{7k-5}{5k-3}=\frac{6l-1}{4l-3}\iff kl+8k+l=6.$$ That is, if $k\ne -1,$

$$l=2\frac{3-4k}{k+1}=-2\left(4-\frac{7}{k+1}\right)=-8+\frac{14}{k+1}.$$ Since $l$ has to be an integer $k+1$ must divide $14.$ So, we have that $k\in\{-15,-8,-3,-2,0,1,6,13\}.$

Note that $k\ne -1$ since if $k=-1$ the equation $kl+8k+l=6$ gives $-8=6$ which doesn't hold.

Comment: If $k=1$, $\frac {7k-5}{5k-3}=\frac 22=1$, if $l=-1$ $\frac {6l-1}{4l-3}=\frac {-7}{-7}=1$.

Comment: @snulty I have realized that. Thank you for noticing it.